# bind list to object list property in xaml (wpf) (Application.Resources)

Tags: wpf, list, xaml, bind

I've been searching a lot in the internet to solve this problem and couldn't find decent solution. this is the problem:(this is a WPF app, in VS2010)
Assume i have this classes:

```
public class Airplane
{
   public string AirplaneName{get;set;}
   public ObservableCollection<People> myPeopleList {get;set;}
}
public class People
{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public string SeatNumber{get;set;}   
}
```

Now I want to create an instance of Airplane class including the people list in the file App.xaml. That is, to create my own resource (Application.Resources). I tried this but I get an exception:

```
<lcl:AirPlaneCollection x:Key="apCollection" >
            <lcl:Airplane  Name="airbus-780" myPeopleList="{StaticResource pList}" >
</lcl:AirPlaneCollection>
        <lcl:PeopleCollection x:Key="pList">
            <lcl:People  Name="name1" SeatNumber="1"/>
           <lcl:People  Name="name2" SeatNumber="2"/>
        </lcl:PeopleCollection>
```

AirPlaneCollection and PeopleCollection is just simple class that inherits from `ObservableCollection<Airplane>` and `ObservableCollection<Poeple>`
when i try to use that resource (Application.Current.Resources["appCollection"] it compile but i get an exception at run time.
my TreeView DataTemplate is performing well because if i instantiate the classes in the code-behind as regular lists(Add ect.) it works flawlessly..what am i doing wrong??
thank in advanced..

Comment: "Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception."

Answer (score 0):

found the solution at last!!
in the Application.Resources the "pList" needs to be declare above "apCollection".
probably the declaration order is important..